# PathORAM with read path eviction

Tags: oblivious-ram

I am currently trying to implement the pathORAM algorithm as describe in this paper:
https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/280.pdf

The paper states that with high probability, the stash size will be bounded by some R.  Is there a way to know what this R will be?  Additionally, is there an intuitive way to understand why it should be bounded? 
Thanks

Comment: That's a pretty specific protocol you are trying to implement. I'd say that this is more of an implementation issue, but I'm a bit reluctant to propose stackoverflow (where the questions are not always that interesting).

Comment: No, the stash is meant to stay small indefinitely. The fact that it happens only after a long time (but then goes wrong very severely) makes it quite hard to diagnose.

Comment: Is this for Elaine Shi's crypto class?

Comment: Since the question was changed and my comment no longer makes sense, the question originally asked about an implementation of Path ORAM where after some large number of accesses the stash started to grow quite quickly.